# python convert a string into a dictionary value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, python-behave

I have a behave tes that i am running and as part of the assert I need to get data out of a data frame, I do this using a dictionary approach.

an example of the step I am running is

```
@then("a new file is created with ATTRIBUTE_NAME values")
def step_impl(context):
    attribute = (attribute)
    context.crm_df = context.pre_processing.get_file_contents_as_df(context.crm_output)
    expected = context.pre_processing.get_expected_crm_as_list(context.table, "attribute_name")
    actual = dict(zip(context.crm_df.HASHED_MSISDN, context.crm_df.ATTRIBUTE_NAME))
    assert all(elem in actual for elem in expected), f"actual {actual} not equal to expected {expected}"
```

What I want to be able to do to make the test more flexiable is pass the ATTRIBUTE_NAME hardcoded value above as a variable

```
@then("a new file is created with {attribute} values")
def step_impl(context, attribute):
    attribute = (attribute)
    context.crm_df = context.pre_processing.get_file_contents_as_df(context.crm_output)
    expected = context.pre_processing.get_expected_crm_as_list(context.table, attribute)
    actual = dict(zip(context.crm_df.HASHED_MSISDN, context.crm_df.attribute))
    assert all(elem in actual for elem in expected), f"actual {actual} not equal to expected {expected}"
```

However

context.crm_df.attribute is failing because attribute is a string.

How do I define the string attribute so that the Dictionary can read it?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this really easily by changing

```
actual = dict(zip(context.crm_df.HASHED_MSISDN, context.crm_df.attribute))
```

to

```
 actual = dict(zip(context.crm_df.HASHED_MSISDN, context.crm_df.get(attribute)))
```